# From which aspects I should evaluate a proof of concept presentation?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management

We are contracting a 6-month worth of test automation project to a testing firm. A proof of concept has been approved by the management.

I have not evaluated a proof of concept presentation myself, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my personal experience on evaluating a test automation PoC:

- Scalability, how easily it is scaled in the future? This aspect manifests itself in a few ways such as how variables are named? How well is the code structured? How encapsulated is it? A code review will tell you all you need to know as for a PoC, there should not be too much code.
- Maintainability, how easily is this test automation framework maintained after it is handed over to you by contractors. Does it require an in-depth programming knowledge to maintain?
- Is it data-driven? I am assuming a test framework is data-driven as it is perhaps the most desirable solution. If it is data-driven, what data sources it uses? Excel or something else?
- Test results reporting? Does it give a brief yet comprehensive test report after each test run? How? E.g. via email and etc.
- What services do contractors offer after this project is handed over to you? Discounted maintenance?